# how to create timelines that have multiple streams that merge and fork off each other?

Tags: excel, project

I found this image / solution online. the source is included. it's a template that uses draw.io to create multiple timelines that look like merged code.

we have many projects that look like this. does anyone know how to do this programmatically in Excel.

The goal is to be able to manipuale the a program with data to generate this timeline.

any help is awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok - so after reaching out to couple of folks / reading online - I am going with using excel line graph with really large markers

and so, I get the following type. I am going to play with style and see if I can make the straight lines into curve lines

I can now overlay text as key markers.

thanks

[image]